Converting MP4 to HLS streams in React Native with FFmpegKit
I want help I am trying to converting to HLS streams from a simple video file and generate multiple video formats from FFmpegKit in react native and store those file to firebase storage.
I am getting issues in the command I don't really know how we can do that with the FFmpegKit in react native if somebody can teach me or make a correct function to generate HLS streams from video and upload those files to the cloud with all the segment file into its master.m3u8 file.
Below is the command I have made but I know it is not correct. Thanks in advance.
export async function convertToHLS(inputFilePath: any, outputFolderPath: any, postDocID: any) {
    try {
        // Define the resolutions and bitrates
        const resolutions = [
            { name: '360p', videoBitrate: '800k', audioBitrate: '128k', resolution: '640:360' },
            { name: '480p', videoBitrate: '1500k', audioBitrate: '128k', resolution: '854:480' },
            { name: '720p', videoBitrate: '3000k', audioBitrate: '128k', resolution: '1280:720' },
            { name: '1080p', videoBitrate: '5000k', audioBitrate: '192k', resolution: '1920:1080' },
            { name: '4K', videoBitrate: '8000k', audioBitrate: '192k', resolution: '3840:2160' }
        ];

        const masterPlaylistPath = `${outputFolderPath}/master.m3u8`;
        const segmentDirectory = `${outputFolderPath}/segments`;
        await RNFS.mkdir(segmentDirectory);

        const outputPaths = resolutions.map(resolution => `${segmentDirectory}/${resolution.name}-output.m3u8`).join(';');
        const command = `-i ${inputFilePath} \
        -vf "split=5[o360p][o480p][o720p][o1080p][o4K]; \
        [o360p]scale=640:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:360:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v360p]; \
        [o480p]scale=854:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=854:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v480p]; \
        [o720p]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v720p]; \
        [o1080p]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1080p]; \
        [o4K]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v4K]" \
        -map "[v360p]" -map "[v480p]" -map "[v720p]" -map "[v1080p]" -map "[v4K]" \
        -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ar 48000 \
        -b:v:0 600k -b:a:0 64k \
        -b:v:1 900k -b:a:1 128k \
        -b:v:2 900k -b:a:2 128k \
        -b:v:3 5000k -b:a:3 192k \
        -b:v:4 8000k -b:a:4 192k \
        -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:360p v:1,a:1,name:480p v:2,a:2,name:720p v:3,a:3,name:1080p v:4,a:4,name:4K" \
        -hls_list_size 0 -threads 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type event -hls_time 3 \
        -hls_flags independent_segments -master_pl_name "name-pl.m3u8" \
        "${outputFolderPath}/encoded/name-%v.m3u8"`;


        await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command);
        console.log('Conversion to HLS completed.');

        // Upload master playlist file to Firebase Storage
        const masterPlaylistPathURL = await storage().ref(`posts/${postDocID}/master.m3u8`).putFile(masterPlaylistPath);
        console.log('Uploaded master playlist file to Firebase Storage.');

        return { masterPlaylistPathURL };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during conversion to HLS:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}```


I have tried it many time by giving it a input file video file but it somehow generating error of different types I don't really know about like this and many others - [example error]



LOG  [out#0/hls @ 0xe3688de0] Output with label 'v360p' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.

